# How to prove injectivity of this group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Imagine a cube with endpoints $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ sitting in $\mathbb R^3$. Color all vertices with even sign. This gives a tetrahedron inside the cube. Let's label the colored vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.

I determined all the matrices corresponding to swapping $v_i$ and $v_j$ (the vertices of the tetrahedron). And these are all possible symmetry transformations of this tetrahedron. Now I want to establish that this symmetry group is isomorphic to $S_4$.

What I have so far:

If $g$ denotes the matrix that swaps $v_i$ and $v_j$ then we map $g$ to the transposition $(ij)$.

That this is a group homomorphism is clear.

Now for surjectivity I argued as follows: Since the symmetric group is generated by transpositions, to show surjectivity, it is enough to show that $\sigma$ maps to any given transposition. But this is clear: Given the transposition $(ij)$ the matrix corresponding to $v_iv_j$ maps to it. Hence $\sigma$ is surjective.

But for injectivity I'm stuck.

> How can I prove that this map is injective?

Comment: The group is finite, so just count the elements! If the numbers are the same then (with these kinds of arguments) the map must be injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ determine a basis namely $\{v_1-v_2, v_1-v_3, v_1-v_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So if a symmetry fixes vectors $v_i$, then it should fix basis also, hence it should be identity.

Comment: Arguing using the basis... of course! Why didn't I think of that. It's neat, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ denote the matrix group you've described: it consists of the $4\times 4$ [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). Then you've told us a homomorphism $f\colon G\to S_4$, and you've shown that $f$ is surjective.

Now we determine $\ker f$; this corresponds to the matrices, $M$, which fix all vertices of the tetrahedron. Thus the matrix has $M_{ii}=1$, for $i=1,2,3,4$. But since it is a permutation matrix, its rows and columns sum to 1, which means all other entries vanish. So $M=id$, which shows that $\ker f$ is trivial, so $f$ is injective.